# How do I get a number of clicks of a given url (not on my website) at a given time?

Tags: web-traffic

Is it possible to get a number of visits of each url that is not on my website? My goal is to get a top-10 article links on a given news website that are read the most. Thanks!

Comment: Use Ajax and jquery

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Like what functions or libraries I should use. Thank you.